# How to give Input tag attribute type button value at Runtime in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

How to give `Input` tag Attribute type button value at Runtime in Meteor JS as shown below:

- `newButton = document.createElement('input');`
- `newButton.value = '';` - Here value i need like as i.e , val ="{{btnValue}}"

I'm not familiar with Meteor JS, so please offer any suggestions.

Html Code I need like as below in Runtime JS:

```
   // Manually Creating button
   <input type="button" id="no" val ="{{btnValue}}">
```

My HTML Code :

```
 <head>
  <title>TICTACTOE App 1.3</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> uname}}
  {{> main}}
  {{> games }}
</body>

<template name="uname">
<h1>Welcome to TICTACTOE App</h1>
<p id="pname"><b>User Name :</b> <input type="text" id="uname" ></p>
</template>  

<template name="main">
     <p id="pno"><b>Layout Number :</b> <input type="text" id="no" ></p>
     <div name="main"></div>
</template>

<template name="games">

  {{#each game}}
    <div>{{turn}} </div>
    <div> {{wturn}}</div>
    <div>{{bval}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Meteor JS:

```
    Counts = new Meteor.Collection('count');
TurnData= new Meteor.Collection('tdata');
BtnValues= new Meteor.Collection('btnvalues');
var x = "X";
var o = "O";
var Whoseturn = "";
var no;
var newButton;
var count = 0;
var IsWin = false;
var IsTurn = true;
var val = "";
var ButtonValue= "";
var btnval;
if (Meteor.isClient)
 {


Template.main.helpers
({
  btnValue: function()
  {
    return BtnValues.findOne();
  }
});

  Template.main.events
  ({
    'click input' : function ()
    {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'

        var  name = document.getElementById('uname');
         console.log(name.value);
         var btnid = event.currentTarget.id;
         ButtonValue = btnid;
         btnval = document.getElementById(btnid);
         console.log(btnid);

        if(btnval.value == '' && btnid != "no" )
        {
             calculateTurn();
             console.log(Whoseturn);
             btnval.value = Whoseturn;
             var myBtnData = BtnValues.findOne();
             BtnValues.update( {_id: myBtnData._id},{ $set:{bval :  btnval} });

        }
     }
  });
  Template.main.events
  ({

    'keydown input#no' : function ()
    {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (event.which == 13) 
        { 
        // 13 is the enter key event
          console.log("You pressed  enter key");
        no = document.getElementById('no');
        count = 0;
        var myTurnData = Counts.findOne();
        Counts.update( {_id: myTurnData._id},{ $set:{turn : count } });
         if(no.value != '')
         {
           document.getElementById('pname').style.visibility = 'hidden';
           document.getElementById('pno').style.visibility = 'hidden';
           UI();
         }
        }
    }
  });
}

function UI()
{
  console.log("*** UI() ***");
  for(var i = 1 ; i <= no.value ; i++)
  {
      //var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      var body = document.getElementsByName('main')[0];
      for(var j = 1 ; j <= no.value ; j++)
      {
         newButton = document.createElement('input');
         newButton.type = 'button';
         newButton.id = 'btn'+i+j; 
         newButton.value = '';////Here value i need like as val ="{{btnValue}}
         body.appendChild(newButton);        
      }
      var newline = document.createElement('br');
      body.appendChild(newline) ;
    }

}

function calculateTurn()
{
   var myTurnData = Counts.findOne();
   count = myTurnData.turn;
   console.log("count="+count); 

   count = count + 1;
   console.log("updated count="+count); 

   Counts.update( {_id: myTurnData._id},{ $set:{turn : count } });

  if(count <= 9)
  {
    var TData = TurnData.findOne();
     IsTurn = true;
    if(count % 2 == 0)
    {
       Whoseturn = o ;
       TurnData.update( {_id: TData._id},{ $set:{wturn : Whoseturn } });
    }
    else
    {

      Whoseturn = x ;
      TurnData.update( {_id: TData._id},{ $set:{wturn : Whoseturn } });
    }
  }
  else
  {
    IsTurn = false;
    console.log(" >= 9");
  }
}
if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
  Meteor.startup(function () 
  {
    // code to run on server at startup
     Counts.insert({turn : count});
     TurnData.insert({wturn : Whoseturn});
     BtnValues.insert({bval : val});

  });
}
```

Comment: Please paste your full HTML code. specifically the part where you have used the `template` tag.

Comment: I posted full code plz check once.@Mr D